# Delphi 5 - XE5 - Saving image to a Nexus 7 Device

Tags: android, delphi, delphi-xe5

I am currently working on downloading an image from a server and saving it to an Android Device.

This all works. The problem I am having is the file is only saved to the device while the app is running I think. The file is downloaded and saved to file on the device and I can load it from file into a TImage ok, but when the application terminates the image seems to get removed.

The next time

Does anyone know why the file is removed?

I am using GetHomePath to get the local path.

I have also tried using System.IOUtils.TPath.GetDocumentsPath to get the local path.

Is the folder a temporary folder perhaps?

Anyway I want to save the image permanently, or until the app is removed, or there is a newer image on the server that needs to be downloaded.

Thanks in advance.

Shane

Comment: What lines are you using to save the file?

Comment: @Sentient` 
  fIDHTTP := TIDHTTP.Create;
 
  Stream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    try
      if FileExists(aDestFileName) then
        DeleteFile(PWideChar(aDestFileName));

      fIDHTTP.Get(aSourceURL, Stream);
      Stream.SaveToFile(aDestFileName);
      Result := TRUE;
`

Comment: I would stick with using TPath.GetDocumentsPath, I believe that is what's intended for storage. Also, in XE5 everytime you run your app from the IDE it seems to uninstall the old version and clear out any data. Does the file exists if you just close and restart your app on the device?

Answer (score 2):

Nexus have tightly secured file system. you can only acces a file saved by some app when that particular application is open.

use can use this methos to store it to permanant visible directory

```
   Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().
```

Comment: Here is the link I was looking for. 

Thanks Guys.

http://chuacw.ath.cx/blogs/chuacw/archive/2013/09/26/getting-the-files-directory-on-android-with-delphi-xe5.aspx